# Can't define my API via Swagger; is this bad design?

Tags: api, rest, swagger

One of our APIs accept certificates from our users. With current design, users dump raw certificate data in the payload and make a POST request with the content type set to **application/x-pkcs12**.
So essentially, our API is accepting raw bytes of a file in the body of the request.

If I try to define this API via Swagger, then I can't do so. Because, correct me if I'm wrong, the parameter of this operation will have to be '**in**' **body** and the '**type**' of this parameter would have to be **file**.
Swagger requires all **body** parameters to have the **Schema** object necessarily, and all parameters of type file should have '**in**' value set to **formData**. Both of these requirements are contradictory to our case.

So my question is, is this Swagger's limitation? Or is this just bad API design, and should we be structuring/designing our API in some other way?

I'm fairly new to the world of APIs so I'm not sure which of the cases it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can still be done.  Your body parameter schema should have type []byte.  When you call the API, your parameter value should be a base-64 encoded string of the file contents.  This is similar to how you would send the contents of a binary .jpg file in the body of a request.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger 2.0 allows parameters of type `file`. This seems to fit your use case.

```
parameters:
- name: cert
  in: formData
  description: The certificate
  required: true
  type: file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is supported in OpenAPI 3.0. The previous version, OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, allowed file uploads using `multipart/form-data` requests only, but 3.0 supports uploading raw files as well.

```yaml
paths:
  /cert:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-pkcs12:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
      responses:
        ...
```

More info: [File Upload](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/)